# I'm trying to import an external Redis database (.RDB file) on a Redis installation on Windows but the new data is not being loaded?

Tags: database, import, redis, nosql

I have been trying for hours to import a .RDB Redis database file into a new installation on my local machine. I have followed all the steps on Stackoverflow stating to basically drop the **dump.rdb** into the installation folder (i.e. what it's condifured to read in the .conf file. See first screenshot).

I make sure that the redis server is not running when I place the file, and when re-start the server and I open **redis-cli** and do something like `keys *` it's saying that there's nothing. What's going on? All of my **.conf** settings are default settings

[image: Directory and file structure]

[image: There's nothing there?!?]

Comment: You need to restart Redis to load the RDB file - what does your log file say?

Comment: I've done that. [9480] 07 Jun 10:34:07.747 * Redis 2.8.19 (00000000/0) 64 bit, stand alone mode, port 6379,
 pid 9480 ready to start.
[9480] 07 Jun 10:34:07.749 # 
Server started, Redis version 2.8.19
[9480] 07 Jun 10:34:11.290 *
 DB loaded from disk: 3.540 seconds
[9480] 07 Jun 10:34:11.291 * 
The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379

Comment: The logged tone suggests that your rdb was loaded... Perhaps you need to `SELECT` the right database? What does `INFO` say, specifically at the end?

Comment: # Keyspace

db2:keys=457985,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
 That's interesting...it reconizes the keys but why wont it let me access them? This is the full text...http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/20H2

Comment: Your keys are in database number 2 - do a `SELECT 2` before you run `KEYS`

Comment: Thank You!. You can submit this as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line from your log suggests that the RDB is indeed loaded:

```
[9480] 07 Jun 10:34:11.290 * DB loaded from disk: 3.540 seconds
```

And this line begotten from `INFO` tells the whole thing:

```
db2:keys=457985,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Your keys are sitting in the database numbered 2, so to access them you'll need to issue the following command upon connecting to Redis:

```
SELECT 2
```

BTW - numbered (a.k.a. "shared") Redis database is a bad habit that you should stop practicing. If you're looking for the reasons why (except this little mixup), read here: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances